# How to parse stdin in C?

Tags: c, fgets

I use `select()` to know when I must read from stdin. I call this function:

```
void
CLI()
{
    char *line=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*32);
    char *cmd=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
    char *arg1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
    char *arg2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != NULL)
    {
        cmd=strtok(line," \n\r\t");
        arg1=strtok(NULL," \n\r\t");
        arg2=strtok(NULL," \n\r\t");

        if(cmd==NULL) break;

        printf("cmd=%s, arg1=%s, arg2=%s",cmd,arg1,arg2);
    }
    free(line);
    free(cmd);
    free(arg1);
    free(arg2);
}
```

Example of input: `#set PAR 0`

What I get:

```
*** Error in './myprogram': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000001cc70f0 ***
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Standard Warning : Please [do not cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: And instead of casting it, you must check that it's not `NULL`.

Comment: And don't `malloc` `cmd`,`arg1` and `arg2` as `strtok` returns a `char*`.

Comment: Do you know what `=` does with pointers? (Or rather, what it doesn't do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problems here *are*

1. `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin`, no that's not what you want. `sizeof()` returns the size of the datatype, not the area pointed by the pointer. You have to supply the amount of memory available for use through that pointer, something like

   `while(fgets(line, 32 , stdin) != NULL)   //sizeof(char) == 1, can be ommitted`
2. After allocating by doing `malloc()` to a pointer, using assignment `=` leads to memory leak. Use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) instead to *copy* the *token* returned by `strtok()` to the required pointer.

Comment: Tryed with strcpy, but I get `segmentation fault`. So much with malloc as without. Btw, fgets requiers line to be initialized.

Comment: @LiLou_ Can you use `gdb` and give us some more info? Which line getting segfault?

Comment: is at fgets. I init line with NULL.

Comment: @LiLou_ I think there is a confusion. you have to allocate memory for all, as you were doing in your code. What i asked you is to 1) follow my point 1. 2 ) instead of `cmd=strtok(line," \n\r\t");`, take a temporary pointer and use like `char *tmp; tmp=strtok(line," \n\r\t"); strcpy(cmd, tmp);`. Hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
char *cmd=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*16);
char *arg1=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
char *arg2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*8);
```

Why? Because the memory you have `malloc`ed is lost here:

```
cmd=strtok(line," \n\r\t");
arg1=strtok(NULL," \n\r\t");
arg2=strtok(NULL," \n\r\t");
```

`strtok` returns a `char*`. You change the location that the pointers point to. This leads to a *memory leak* as you haven't `free`ed the allocated memory. You don't need

```
free(cmd);
free(arg1);
free(arg2);
```

once you have removed the three calls to `malloc` as mentioned above.

Also, [Don't cast the result of `malloc` and family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Do note that `sizeof(char)` is 1 as multiplying it with another number in the `malloc` isn't needed.